What exactly is a VRF?
Random numbers are useful in many use cases such as blockchain. I know many blockchains or smart contracts employ VRF to generate "provably fair random numbers". But what exactly is a VRF?
I've read some sections of RFC 9381 which describes VRF, but it seems that a VRF is NOT a function that generates a random number out of nothing. In another word, an alpha value is required as the input to generate both the hash and the proof. Then the hash is used as the random number.
So, a random and unpredictable value alpha is required, right? But if I already have alpha, why can't I just use this alpha directly as the random number? What is a VRF used for?
I understand digital signature algorithms. I understand I can verify a message is signed by a party (who has a secret key) with the signature provided by that party. I understand I can verify the VRF output. So what? That doesn't mean anything. A VRF provider just uses an already-existed random number to generate another pseudorandom number, and charges users money... I'm confused.

A full answer will come later. But in brief, a VRF is a public key counterpart of a pseudo-random function (PRF). A PRF is used as local PRG by simply evaluating it on unique inputs. But, given a claimed PRF output, I cannot verify that the output is computed correctly. So I have no reason for trusting someone's data as truly random. So, how do we get a source of public randomness? A VRF guarantees that the output was computed correctly. Recall: for a random function, the output is indistinguishable from random.

As for applications: this enables capabilities akin to using the moon as a global, public randomness source (to implement a lottery, for example). Again, the important thing to note is that the input (alpha) doesn't need to be random or anything, it just needs to be unique for the VRF to function as a verifiable PRG.

@MarcIlunga Thanks! But if a VRF is only a public key counterpart of a PRF, then the VRF output is not a fair random number, right? Because the VRF provider (the party that holds the secret key) could determine the input as it wishes. If this VRF is used for a lottery, then the VRF provider could choose a "good" input so that it could win the prize. Though it can provide a verifiable random number, this random number is not fair. Is fairness not a consideration of VRF?

"If a VRF is only a public key counterpart of a PRF, then the VRF output is not a fair random number, right?". This is not accurate. Whenever a random function is queried with a new input, it produces a new random value... Just like querying a secure CSPRNG each time, you get a random value. If large enough, the probability you get your desired output is negligible. So you can choose the input, but you have no control over the output.

But there are two other concerns to take into account. We need the inputs to be unique for randomness to be meaningful for each new random number we want. In applications, this is usually guaranteed by higher-level protocols. Second randomness guarantees really only hold for honestly generated VRF keys. This concern is outside the realm of VRF. Applications typically address that concern by decentralizing the VRF somehow. So, as long as one of the VRF “servers” behaves honestly, the VRF key is as good as an honestly generated key.

A random function $f$ is like a random book in the Library of Babel.
If you have the book in front of you, you can open it up to find what's on page 316, giving the value $f(316)$.
If you don't have the book in front of you, you have no hope of guessing what's on that page—all possible page contents, that is, page-length strings of printable characters, are equally probable.
(It's a very long book, so you can, e.g., encode a string like "example.com" into a page number like 122669988979119183248977773 and look up that page in the book.)
Certain applications, such as DNSSEC NSEC5, make very particular use of a random function for their security properties.
With a VRF:

There is exactly one book (per VRF key pair).
Only one party, call him Bob, can read the book directly (with the VRF private key).
Nobody besides Bob has any hope of guessing what's on any given page of the book (verifiable random function).
Nevertheless, when Bob shares a page of the book (the VRF output) with Alice, Mallory, or anyone else (anyone who knows the VRF public key), he can convince them (by showing them the VRF proof) that it is a page from the same book every time and from the page number he claims (the VRF input), even if he's never revealed that page before—he's not just randomly making up pages as he goes.

This dialogue in six parts on DNSSEC NSEC5 dramatizes how the security properties of a VRF are combined with traditional public-key signature to manage operational costs and risks in a DNSSEC.

Thanks! Regarding your "book and library" example, since Bob is the only party who can read the book (has the secret key), he could determine which page to read, right? Yes he could indeed convince others that the revealed page is from the book, but that page is chosen by him. So the VRF output is not fair, since it's controlled by Bob. Is fairness not a consideration of VRF?
